# Boxes in Markdown

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, github-flavored-markdown

I want to know if I can get boxes like the ones around the mathematical symbols in the image using Markdown to highlight something.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxes you're referring to are inline code snippets. Use ` around text to make it so.

Example:

`` `your_highlighted_text` ``

You can highlight multiple lines (of code, typically) using ``` instead of `.